# powershell : replace character in TXT file in certain position

Tags: powershell

Hello I have a txt file like this (name test.txt)

```
        Z     , HADEtatPat ,"HAD : Evolution de l'‚tat du patient" ,44                           
////////B     , HADDialyse ,"Dialyse hors centre depuis HAD"   , 21                          
       W     , HADAutre   ,"HAD : Hors protocole"            , 13                    
//        p     , HADPIA     ,"HAD : PIA sejour vers SSR/PSY"     , 17                      
        x     , HADS‚aEJ   ,"D‚part vers S‚ance de Chimio./Radioth‚./Dialyse dansé " , 22
```

I want replace the character 1 and 2 of line 4 by '@@'

how to do this

I try

```
Get-Content test.txt | Select -Index 3 | replace-char position 1,2 by '@' | replace-content test.txt
```

but not working
thx for help

I need

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following for the simple case of replacing the first two characters of a specified line:

```
$line = 0
(Get-Content test.txt | Foreach-Object {
    if ($line++ -eq 2) { 
        $_ -replace '^..','@@' 
    } else { $_ } 
}) | Set-Content test.txt
```

`$line` will increment to the current line number before being evaluated against `2`. Once line `2` (starting from line `0`) is found, the first two characters `^..` (regex expression for beginning of string `^` and any two characters `.`) will be replaced by `@@`.

For replacing characters `3` and `6` on line 2, you could use a similar technique as above:

```
$line = 0
(Get-Content test.txt | Foreach-Object {
    if ($line++ -eq 2) { 
        $_ -replace '(?<=^.{3}).|(?<=^.{6}).','@'
    } else { $_ } 
}) | Set-Content test.txt
```

---

If you want to make this more dynamic with variable parameters, you can do the following to replace characters at positions `3` and `5` on line `3`:

```
$line = 3 # Starting from 0
$characters = 3,5 # Array of character positions starting from 0
$replacechar = '@' # Character you want to insert
$count = 0

(Get-Content test.txt | Foreach-Object {
    if ($count++ -eq $line) {
        $temp = $_.ToCharArray()
        foreach ($pos in $characters) {
            $temp[$pos] = $replacechar
        }
        -join $temp
    } else { $_ }
}) | Set-Content test.txt
```

---

If you are not opposed to using `System.Text.StringBuilder` objects, then you can do the following to replace characters at positions `3` and `5` on line `3`:

```
$line = 3 # Starting from 0
$characters = 3,5 # Starting from 0
$replacechar = '@'

$content = Get-Content test.txt
foreach ($pos in $characters) {
    $content[$line] = ([System.Text.StringBuilder]$content[$line]).Replace($content[$line][$pos],$replacechar,$pos,1).ToString()
}
$content | Set-Content test.txt
```

Comment: thank you and if I want replace the character at position X , how i do this? (example line 3 like your code and position 5)

Comment: If you want to replace character 6 starting from 0, you can do  `$_ -replace '(?<=^.{6}).','@'`

Comment: @guillaumezac, I added a second code block. See if that is more of what you are looking for.